# How do I prevent font smoothing from turning on when changing theme?

Tags: windows-7, themes, cleartype

When I change my Windows 7 environment theme via `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization`, it turns on font smoothing, even if the themes I'm switching between were saved with font smoothing turned off.

Am I doing something wrong when saving themes that doesn't save my font smoothing setting, or is it a bug by Microsoft? In the meantime, how do I disable font smoothing along with switching a theme?

Comment: You should start a bounty on this question.

Comment: You cannot save font smoothing information into theme, because themes does not support this.

Comment: @Alexanderius well, then what part of Windows decides to switch it on anyway? Does that have settings I can change?

Comment: You can try to disable all font smoothing:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/disable-all-font-smoothing-in-windows-7-ie/f180e803-3317-4433-8fd2-63aadaecc2d2

Comment: @Alexanderius thanks, but no, thanks. I've already asked about how to disable font smoothing for good, but this theme switching disaster just keeps messing it up.

Comment: Font smoothing is controlled by the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`, value of [FontSmoothing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978612.aspx). Could you track what happens to FontSmoothing as you turn it on, off, and install a new theme.

Comment: @harrymc If I had some tools to do that, probably. How can I watch that key?

Comment: The tool is regedit - navigate to the above key, note down the value of FontSmoothing, do the manipulation, type F5 in regedit to refresh, then note down the new value. Many tutorials exist for regedit, for example [this one](http://www.gammadyne.com/registry.htm).

Comment: @harrymc oh, I thought you're gonna propose some tool to watch which process modifies it so I could block it or freeze the key value. Oh well.

Comment: I cannot propose anything if I don't know what the problem is. If you prefer to make available one of your themes, I could have a look at it.

Comment: @harrymc I'm talking about toggling between Windows Basic and Aero themes. There is no custom anything involved. It's as simple as default themes. They are the problem.

Comment: The default display font (Segoe UI) is not designed to look good with ClearType turned off. For this reason, globally disabling font smoothing is not really possible because most of the interface will still smooth fonts edges, no matter which settings you use. As you have noticed, every time you change themes smoothing will be turned on again (unless it was disabled and you switch to the Windows Classic theme).

Comment: @and31415 it's still smoothed where it's used, but all other fonts are not. Which is fine by me, but I don't want that to change automatically when switching between themes.

Comment: @user1306322 For what is worth, ClearType won't be turned on when you use a 256-color resolution, and for bitmap fonts, vector fonts, device fonts, Type 1 fonts, or Postscript OpenType fonts without TrueType outlines. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Even locking the whole `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` registry key doesn't seems to have any effect.

Comment: I think the only way to prevent font smoothing from turning on would be patching the code where the SystemParametersInfo API function is called to turn on ClearType upon switching themes. Either that, or programming a custom font smoothing monitor application, and turn it off when activated (not really efficient).